# Как запретить чтение / запись файла если он открыт другим процессом

Tags: linux, c, bash, безопасность

Есть пользователь `А` который хранит в своем файле секретные данные (зашифрованный с помощью `openssl` txt файл). Данный файл лежит в зашифрованном виде, но у пользователя `А` есть ключ к этом файлу и он может расшифровать его (только он и никто больше) и прочитать / записать что-либо в него после ввода ключа. Проблема в том что когда пользователь `А` открывает этот секретный файл (работает с его содержимым в расшифрованом виде), то другие пользователи системы (или допустим хакеры) могут прочитать секретное содержимое этого файла, например сделать `cat /path/to/secret.txt` и с легкостью получить содержимое файла (ведь `А` пользователь в данный момент его редактирует)

Как сделать так чтобы другие пользователи системы не могли открывать / читать этот файл (когда он открыт). Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать.

Comment: Так вопрос о процессах или о пользователях? От других пользователей файл защищается элементарно через chmod или umask

Comment: Ну а от хакеров защищаться просто бессмысленно, потому что если с безопасностью всё настолько плохо, что в систему уже проникли хакеры, то они всё равно всегда смогут прочитать содержимое прямо из памяти редактора вообще в обход любых файлов

Comment: @andreymal, здравствуйте, речь о процессах, чтобы даже суперпользователь не смог открыть файл, если он редактируется каким-либо процессом, как бы некая блокировка происходила - предупреждение, мол файл в данный момент открыт другим процессом, у вас нет к нему доступа (как-то так ...)

Comment: Суперпользователь (и хакер с правами суперпользователя) по определению может всё, так что это невозможно

Comment: @andreymal, понял, спасибо за рекомендации ... размечтался я наверное)

Comment: Можно удалить открытый файл до записи в него расшифрованных данных. У процесса, который его открыл, сохраняется доступ к содержимому через файловый дескриптор. Из файловой же системы, доступ к этому содержимому исчезает (нет линка ни из одного каталога). При восстановлении пишете уже опять зашифрованные данные, потом делаете rename

Comment: @avp идём в /proc/PID/fd и без проблем читаем содержимое из нужного дескриптора

Comment: @andreymal, согласен, это же Линукс... Не знаю, подробно не изучал, а можно ли с помощью каких-нибудь credentials закрыть доступ другим процессам к дескриптору? (Я понимаю, что через /dev/mem (или что-то вроде) всегда можно прочесть память, но это уже сложнее для примитивной реализации)

Comment: @avp вообще в недавних линуксах придумали lockdown, который ограничивает доступ даже к /dev/mem, так что может даже можно что-то придумать, но я тоже подробно не изучал)

Comment: ...хотя это всё равно размышления не в ту сторону, ведь суперпользователь даже с lockdown всё равно может в любой момент просто пропатчить программу, отключив в ней все запреты ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal ну вот тут есть моменты) я не могу рутом открыть папку созданную пользователем postgres на nfs шаре и не могу её чмоднуть) потом есть уровни безопасности в астре, аппармор и селинукс. С правильной политикой можно извратиться и сделать uid 0 ограниченным в операциях su

Comment: @eri если доступ к nfs есть хотя бы у кого-то, то в любом случае можно пропатчить этого самого кого-то или прочитать его память из /dev/mem

Comment: @andreymal через аппармор можно прикрыть сисколы к /dev/mem? Тогда прийдется писать драйвер) в любом случае это гонка со временем

Comment: В таких делах главное чтоб ценность секрета была меньше ценности хакера который может его взять

Comment: @eri есть подозрение, что по такому критерию для автора окажется вполне безопасен даже chmod 777 (:

Answer (score 2):

В openssl есть потоковые функции на  чтение и запись. Если не требуется произвольного доступа (seek, trunk), то можно не хранить расшифрованный файл на диске.